# Is there an intelligent editor for ReST files?

Tags: python, restructuredtext, python-sphinx, docutils

I'm just learning Sphinx, and I need to edit ReST files. Is there an intelligent editor for it? Like, an editor that gives me code coloration, easy indentation, code completion (hopefully), etc.

Comment: what kind of code completion would you be looking for? I'm in the process of writing a vim plugin for restructured text, so I'd def be interested in that.

Answer (score 6):

`vi` is very good at this.  I was just editing some `.rst` files right now and it colors the headings, monospaced text, etc.  The macros let you very quickly turn text into headings and whatnot.

Answer (score 6):

Emacs with rst-mode: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/emacs.html

Comment: Very rich RST support. Daily in use. Highly recommend! +1

Comment: rst-mode needs table-mode, to edit tables. But it is very slow, so that one can see a lag when inserting characters. It knows only tables made with `+` and `-`, but not `=` which is available in spinx too.

Answer (score 2):

[Leo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leo_%28text_editor%29) does some of this.

More info from [Creating Documents with Leo](http://webpages.charter.net/edreamleo/rstplugin3.html)  :

1. "View nodes can show you many different views of your writing simultaneously..."
2. "... The rst3 command converts an @rst tree to rST and then sends this text to docutils or Sphinx for further processing."
3. "... automatically creates rST sections from headlines"

There are additional features mentioned later in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Gedit has a ReST plugin which supports syntax highlighting, keyboard shortcuts ("snippets"), and HTML preview.

- http://textmethod.com/wiki/ReStructuredTextToolsForGedit

Answer (score 2):

There is also a rst mode for the Jed editor:
http://jedmodes.sf.net/mode/rst/

Answer (score 2):

eclipse has an editor that provides all these features:

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/rest-editor

also

http://resteditor.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

jEdit also has ReST highlighting, but no ReST specific auto-completion features (it does support macros though).

I would opt for vim or Cream, personally.

Answer (score 1):

I use **vim** and have some useful mappings in my .vimrc:

```
nnoremap <leader>1 yypVr=
nnoremap <leader>2 yypVr- 
nnoremap <leader>3 yypVr'
nnoremap <leader>4 yypVr`
vmap <silent> <leader>b :call BulletList()<cr>

" Bullet List
function! BulletList()
  let lineno = line(".")
  call setline(lineno, "* " . getline(lineno))
endfunction
```

And often create vim macros on th fly depending on the file I have to restructure

Comment: Isn't the `BulletList()` just a `I* `?

Answer (score 1):

A while ago I tried the Atom Editor https://atom.io/. It has the benefits of even displaying a preview showing possible images and renders the sections correctly, even formulas are displayed. The syntax highlighting is supported, but there is not much to highlight in ReST anyway.

In order to make it work you have to install pandoc and the atom packages `language-restructuredtext` and `rst-preview-pandoc`. You activate the preview with `CTRL-SHIFT-E`.

Another possibility is Visual Studio Code, which I didn't tried.

But after a while I'm relying on simple NotePad++, as there is not so much benefit in an nice editor, as ReST is already so simple.